# MySQL: Select from table A, if ID matches 2 (or arbitrary n) rows in table B

Tags: mysql, join, tagging

The scenario is quite straight forward: I have content in table A and tags for contents in table B:

```
Table A:
+----+-------+-...
| id | title | ...
+----+-------+-...

Table B:
+------+-----+
| id_A | tag |
+------+-----+
```

I want to select all content rows in A, that have tag 'foo':

```
SELECT A.* FROM A, B WHERE A.id = B.id_A AND B.tag = 'foo'
```

So far, that's simple.

My problem is: How can I select content rows, that have **both** tag 'foo' **and** tag 'bar'? Especially, how can I select rows that have `n` tags 'foo', 'bar', ... for **arbitrary `n > 1`**?

A solution would be to join B `n` times, but that feels bad, and I assume, that it's not really performant.

Since I use MySQL, PHP and PDO with prepared statements, if there is a solution that goes without necessary string concatenation (like in the 'Join `n` times' solution) in the PHP part, that would be my favourite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    a
WHERE   (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    b
        WHERE   b.id_a = a.id
                AND b.tag IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
        ) = 3
```